# Laravel 5.5 about Model

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

I want to have a Chapter model that contains a district column contained multiple District model.
But I have no idea how to link it. I just have done with model and migration.

```html
class Chapter extends Model
{
  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable = [
      'name',
  ];

  public function districts()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(District::class);
  }
}
```

```html
class District extends Model
{
  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable = [
      'name',
  ];

  public function chapter()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo(Chapter::class);
  }
  
  public function blocks()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Block::class);
  }
}
```

What should I do after this? Do I need to mention the district in the chapter migration file?

Here is my migration file.

```js
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateChaptersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('chapters', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->indexed();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('chapters');
    }
}
```

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateDistrictsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('districts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->indexed();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('districts');
    }
}
```

Do I need to link them in the $fillable side?

Comment: You have done it correctly already.  I am assuming that you have a `chapter_id` column in your districts table

Comment: maybe you can also post the migrations for creating the 2 tables

Comment: Your schema is missing the relation. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link them using the data structure, so that Laravel [Eloquent Relation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships) can take advantage of this. See below.

First off, make sure your database structures have relevant attributes. E.g. your migration should look somewhat similar to this

```
class CreateDistrictsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('districts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            // all district related columns
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('chapter_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

The `chapter_id` column in the `districts` table acts as a foreign key constraint and joins all the districts under a specific chapter.

In the `Chapter` Class, you need to define a relation like below (which you have done):

```
public function districts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(District::class);
}
```

Then, you can retrieve all the districts for a given chapter, by calling `districts()` method. For example, to get all districts for `chapter Id = 1`, you can do this:

```
App\Chapter::find(1)->districts
```